# SQL Server 2005 Query Scheduler to Auto Update Table

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks

I need to update one of my tables periodically, say each 30 minutes.
Should I go for Stored Procedure with SQL Server Agent ( not that much aware ) :-( or something else?

Comment: whenever it comes to periodically updating sql you should go to scheduler

Comment: You can write your update as stored procedure and schedule its execution in SQL Server Agent job

Comment: @RAHULSR Hope Server Agent is available with SQL Server Management Studio 2005 ?